# Does PBKDF2 generate the unique hash?

Tags: security, cryptography, pbkdf2, hashalgorithm

I want to generate a hash of some data.
Going through some hash algorithms I could find out bcrypt and PBKDF best suitable for my application.
There might be the case that with the different data algorithm generates a same hash (like in MD5, it could generate the same hash for different sort of data).

By the reviews of many expertise, bcrypt is the best secure hash algorithm and its provides uniqueness among different hashes.

But, does the PBKDF2 provides the uniqueness for hash?

**Edit 1**

I need to generate hash with the same input data (hash key will be generated more than one time for same input) but it should not generate same hash for different input data (might happens in some hash algorithms).

Comment: First, this is the wrong forum. Second, what properties do you actually need and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you want to generate cryptographic keys based on password or you just want to get unique identifier for some data?

Comment: I want cryptographic (hash)key based on some unique identifier, and that  hash key should be uniquely identify (should not have the same key with different id/password). My concern is there might be case that hashing algorithm may generates the same hash key for different id/password. So PBKDF2 take cares of it like bcrypt does?

Comment: KDFs (Key Derivation Functions) such as PBKDF2 and bcrypt include a work factor (also know as key stretching) used to defend against dictionary attacks. You *must* explain what your use case is as we do not even know what threats you need protection from. For all I know, CRC32 might be the right primitive to use in your case!

Comment: *If* all you need is a hash that uniquely represent the input data, then most likely any current cryptographic Message Digest (such as SHA2) will suffice. The chances of a collision occurring are so small they can be ignored. *But* we can't tell as long as you do not explain what your use case is.

Comment: @ErwanLegrand, yes! i just need a hash which is uniquely defined. Using MD5 or SHA2, as per my understandings it does not provides assurity of uniqueness so there might be same case of having _same hash_ key with _different input_ this is one thing and second thing is everytime i need _same hash_ for _same input_

Comment: Hash functions cannot provide uniqueness if the source domain is bigger than the domain of the hash values, which is almost aways the case. Even if the source domain is small, there will always be the change of collision, i.e. two source values map to the same hash value. So whatever you choose or do, they cannot provide uniqueness.

Comment: @Erwan Legrand: Be careful to say that collisions can be ignored. It depends on the use case how likely they (keep the birthday paradoxon in mind) occur and if they can be ignored (or how bad it could get if we hit a collision). If uniqueness is strict requirement I would not rely on a hash but on a unique value issued by a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithms such as one of the SHA-2 suffice. The hash generated is not unique to the message. It is even true that there are an infinite number of messages that hash to the same value. The trick is that it is impossible to find one of the other messages that create this hash.

The chance of generating a collision when generating two hashes with different messages is equal to 1/2^256 for SHA-256. You could however generate and store hashes and then calculate the chance that one of all the possible *pairs* is identical. In that case the birthday problem is in effect. That's why a hash only provides half the bits of security. So the chance of generating a collision giving 2^128 hashes is (about) 1/2^128 or 1 in 340282366920938463463374607431768211456. This is why you only have to worry about collisions in broken hash functions such as MD5 (and possibly SHA-1 in the near future).

Actually the inner state of PBKDF2 is the same as the internal hash that is used. Using PBKDF2 (besides being a *Key Derivation Function* instead of a hash) won't help you at all. It is just as vulnerable (or rather, *not* vulnerable) to collisions as the inner hash.

Comment: Thanks Maarten for clarification. (y)